# Webscraping using selenium, beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently scraping a real estate website that is using javascript. My process starts by scraping a list containing many different href links for single listings, appending these links to another list and then pressing the next button. I do this til the the next button is no longer clickable.

my problem is that after collecting all the listings (~13000 links) the scraper doesn't move onto the second part where it opens the links and gets the info I need. Selenium doesn't even open to move onto the first element of the list of links.

heres my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'next')))
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find(id = 'search_main_div')
        classtitle =  table.find_all('p', class_= 'title')
        for aaa in classtitle:
            hrefsyo =  aaa.find('a', href = True)
            linkstoclick = hrefsyo.get('href')
            houselinklist.append(linkstoclick)
        element.click()
    except:
        pass
```

After this I have another simple scraper that goes through the list of listings, opens them in selenium and collects data on that listing.

```
for links in houselinklist:
    print(links)
    newwebpage = links
    driver.get(newwebpage)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    .
    .
    .
    . more code here
```

Comment: Where is the link you are scraping ?

Comment: https://www.28hse.com/en/rent/house-type-g1

Comment: What error did you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `while True:` creates a loop that runs infinity. Your `except` clause has a `pass` statement, which means once an error occurs, the loop just continues to run. Instead it can be written as

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'next')))
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find(id = 'search_main_div')
        classtitle =  table.find_all('p', class_= 'title')
        for aaa in classtitle:
            hrefsyo =  aaa.find('a', href = True)
            linkstoclick = hrefsyo.get('href')
            houselinklist.append(linkstoclick)
        element.click()
    except:
        break # change this to exit loop
```

once an error occurs, the loop will `break` and move on to the next line of code

or you can just you can eliminate the while loop and just loop over your list of href links with a for loop

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
hrefLinks = ['link1','link2','link3'.....]
for link in hrefLinks:
    try:
        driver.get(link)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'next')))
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        table = soup.find(id = 'search_main_div')
        classtitle =  table.find_all('p', class_= 'title')
        for aaa in classtitle:
            hrefsyo =  aaa.find('a', href = True)
            linkstoclick = hrefsyo.get('href')
            houselinklist.append(linkstoclick)
        element.click()
    except:
        pass #pass on error and move on to next hreflink
```